# CodeIgniter проблема с ссесиями

Tags: сессия, php, codeigniter

Добрый день, я использую CodeIgniter Framework уже достаточно давно, и временами были жалобы на то что вебсайт после перехода на какую нибудь страницу скидывал сессии и пользователям необходимо было заново логиниться. 
Вот настройки сессии которые у меня прописаны в конфиге:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'sessionsname';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 86400; // 1 day
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = $config['sess_expiration'];
```

Позавчера я захотел проверить один из action'ов. Как устроен мой сайт, у пользователя есть ссылка `http://website.com/$1/$2` это две переменные обязательны для работы со следующими страницами. Т.е. я получаю в index action две переменные и сохраняю их в сессиях так:

```
$this->sessions->set_userdata('var1', $var1);
$this->sessions->set_userdata('var2', $var2);
```

Далее во всех последующих action'ах я проверяю эти две переменные, если их нет вывожу сообщение что Session Expired. И так в функцию проверки этих двух переменных я также добавил код отправки мне письма если эти переменные не найдены в сессия, т.е. хотел проверить на сколько часто встречается ситуация с session expiration. И за два дня я получил более 500 писем с уведомление что в сессии не найдены эти две необходимые переменные. Если честно я в шоке, такое ощущение что CodeIgner просто не устанавливает сессия для большинства моих клиентов. Ниже пример письма что я получаю как уведомление:

```
    DateTime: 2014-08-08 03:22:13

Not found dropzone ID and calendar ID
Is Robot: , Robot Name: 
Is Browser: 1, Browser Name: Safari
Is Mobile:1, Mobile Agent: Apple iPhone
User sessions: 
Array
(
    [session_id] => 03cf5bec8720858d47df0c568df02cce
    [ip_address] => 66.168.144.101
    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D2
    [last_activity] => 1407448776
    [user_data] => 
)

Debug trace:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file] => /var/www/burblebookings/application/controllers/index.php
            [line] => 4099
            [function] => get_debug_trace
            [class] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [file] => /var/www/burblebookings/application/controllers/index.php
            [line] => 311
            [function] => check_variables
            [class] => Index
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [file] => 
            [line] => 
            [function] => choose_date
            [class] => Index
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [file] => /var/www/burblebookings/system/core/CodeIgniter.php
            [line] => 359
            [function] => call_user_func_array
            [class] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [file] => /var/www/burblebookings/index.php
            [line] => 208
            [function] => require_once
            [class] => 
        )

)
```

За весь период работы с сайтов и тестов на всех устройствах у самого ни разу не выходило подобной проблемы с сессиями.

Answer (score 1):

ну у CI с сессиями вроде все норм) 1) Какая версия CI. 2) Включено ли отображение ошибок? 3) Попробуйте `sess_time_to_update` - изменить на 300 (изначальное значение) на пару дней и посмотреть.

Comment: Версия CI 2.1.3 
Ошибки выключены на лайв сервере, но включено логирование, ошибок PHP в логах нет.
Изначально стояла `session_time_to_update = 300`, но прочитав много инфы из интернета большинство советовало увеличить значение этой директивы, т.к. именно при обновлении сессий CI сбрасывает `session_key` и это может приводить к не действительности старых сессий

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'pi_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 86400;  
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;  
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE; 
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 86400;
```

> проверено у себя, работает